# How do I get the navigation pane to stop being popped-out in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

By default, the navigation pane in Microsoft Word appears on the left side of the screen, and is a fixed part of the interface.

However, I was (stupidly) fiddling around, and pressed "Pop-Out" (or something like that) in the drop-down menu next to the close button for the navigation pane. As a result, it is now a separate window on top of the normal interface, which can be moved around.

How do I get it to go back to the way it was before? Like other pop-out windows, the popped-out navigation pane disappears from view when I tab to another app, which I find extremely annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Click on the arrow on the right side of `Navigation`.
- Select `Move`. Move it to the left of the screen.
- When it reaches the left border, it will be pinned to the left side.

[image]